# How to keep a running balance of transactions and get the amount after the transactions

Tags: mysql

I have to Write a query that uses a variable to list all transactions, sorted by date, performed by the customer with the ID 1. The variable should keep a running balance to show what the customer's new balance is after each transaction. The final output should give the date, amount of the transaction, and current balance after that transaction.

**Table**

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| customer_id  | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| last_created | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| amount       | decimal(6,2)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT last_created, amount , sum(amount) as moneyspent FROM transactions where 
customer_id = 1   ORDER BY  last_created;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @total = 0; 
SELECT last_transaction, amount ,@total := @total + amount AS runningtotal 
FROM sakila_payment 
ORDER BY last_transaction;
```